# how i add value to empty column based other column name

Tags: python, pandas

Framework:

| Name | cater |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 4 | c |
| 5 | d |
| 6 | b |
| 7 | b |
| 8 | c |

what I want:

array = [3.234,2.467,4.56,4.7]

| Name | cater | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 3.234 |
| 2 | a | 3.234 |
| 3 | b | 2.467 |
| 4 | c | 4.56 |
| 5 | d | 4.7 |
| 6 | b | 2.467 |
| 7 | b | 2.467 |
| 8 | c | 4.56 |

i know this is a little weird, i just want to put array values to correct position based cater names.
i def a function try to make that happen, dont know why i just add the first array in the correct postion, others still null, i am poor with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.map()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

framework = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": np.arange(8),
    "cater": ['a','a','b','c','d','b','b','c',]
})

map_ = {'a': 3.234, 'b': 2.467, 'c': 4.56, 'd': 4.7}

framework["average"] = framework["cater"].map(map_)
print(framework)
```

out:

```
   name cater  average
0     0     a    3.234
1     1     a    3.234
2     2     b    2.467
3     3     c    4.560
4     4     d    4.700
5     5     b    2.467
6     6     b    2.467
7     7     c    4.560
```